# Using jQuery to achieve toggling, but I am missing something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an online calculator for the quadratic function with different variable answers.  I am doing it to kill curiousity by using one ID input and four functions to control a variety of toggling, however I am only getting input A to show it.  When I do the exact same thing for b and change its conditional ID's around, it acted like a and behaved exactly like A.

That's the HTML portion, and I am using jQuery to toggle effects to show some but not all inputs.

```
<div class="left">
    <ul class="nav"><h3>Menu and Solve tabs</h3>        
        <li><a href="#" onclick="what();" id="togglesolve">Toggle Solve Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="solveA();" id="solve">Solve A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="solveB();" id="solve">Solve B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="solveC();" id="solve">Solve C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="solveX();" id="solve">Solve X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="how();" id="togglehow">How to solve</a></li>
        <li><a href="MathApp_Home.html">Return Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content"><h3>This is where to insert your numbers.</h3>
    <ul class="nav" name="quad"><p>Quadratic formula:<br /> ax^2+bx+c=0</p><br />
        <li><p>The formula you are solving for is:<br /><spam id="formula"></spam></p></li>
        <li><p id="a">Input A:</p><input class="input" name="a" id="a"/></li>
        <li><p id="b">Input B:</p><input class="input" name="b" id="b"/></li>
        <li><p id="c">Input C:</p><input class="input" name="c" id="c"/></li>
        <li><p id="x">Input X:</p><input class="input" name="d" id="x"/></li>
        <br />
        <li><p>Answer 1 to variable<spam id="variableinputalpha"></spam><br /><spam id="answer"></spam></p></li>
        <li><p>Answer 2 to variable<spam id="variableinputbeta"></spam><br /><spam id="answer2"></spam></p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#togglesolve").click(function what(){
        $("a#solve").toggle(1000);
    });
    $("a#togglehow").click(function how(){
        $("#howto").toggle(1000);
    });
    $("#solve").click(function solveA(){
        $("#a, p#a").hide(1000)
        $("#b, #c, #x, p#b, p#c, p#x").show(1000);
    });
    $("solve").click(function solveB(){
        $("#b, p#b").hide(1000)
        $("#a, #c, #x, p#a, p#c, p#x").show(1000);
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make an array or make the functions different from the selector?  And let me know if I am asking the wrong questions.  Still learning, and thank you for the help!

Comment: IDs should be unique document-wide.

Comment: it is, its simply short for now for the prototyping phase, however i will change it once it is complete.

Comment: id="solve" is repeating.

Comment: switch those ids to classes maybe?

Comment: Why? Use different IDs from the start then you'll never have to worry about it again. Besides it will cause issues along the way.

Comment: the solve id is used to hide the entire solve id rows by togglesolve id, never colsidered class, however i worry it might clash with the nav class in the ul

Comment: jQuery only acts on the first ID it finds. Write valid HTML and be happy.

Comment: plus @CodingEnthusiast i would have an error of dulpcation of id's if i were to hide and show a few.

Comment: what is stopping me from making oddly named id's is the fact i need to show and hide some of the inputs that matches with the formulas accordingly

Comment: i'll come back when I am a bit more valid

Comment: 1) Don't use inline click events. Use selectors instead. The inline click event and the jQuery selectors fire simultaneously. This will cause multiple code paths to execute. 2) Ids should be always be unique. You can repeat or group similar elements using classes. 3) The tag element before the # is optional e.g. a#toggleSolve can be #toggleSolve. 4) Did you mean span tag? 5) Use meaningfully named functions instead of putting everything in click even handlers.

Comment: is there a different event handler that works when you click on one of the solve links?

the only thing i had learned that was useful was the click because of the "button links" above.  by span tag, and plese forgive me cause im new at this, but what are they, unless u mean spam?

Comment: i changed the solve on the top to class and now doesn't function...

Comment: actually ty guys, i overlooked it. I can set the "a#solve" to "a.solve" to make the toggle work then add the id's in to see if i can try that way.  Sorry if i had provided frustration.  Im never the greatest to ask the questions.  AND the If and Else statement....

Comment: how do i add the conditional IF and ELSE statement in jQuery

Comment: if you wanna use if else use java script you may find [this](http://css-plus.com/2011/07/jquery-if-else-statements/) usefull

Comment: @RinoRaj  now i noticed it, thanks!  is there a way to edit it around?

Comment: @GarethCompton I have edited the question. Removed the id and converted it into class

Comment: @RinoRaj is there a selector for the derivative "name" like "class" and "id"?

Comment: or if there is a way to write options for jQuery like If Else in javascript

Answer (score 0):

As i looked into the "undefined portion" I have formulas on javascript and jquery, some onclick functions is only jquery, it appears as to be "undefined" because the specific function is not defined in javascript, making it appear of having errors.  Toggling with jQuery is a lot easier than doing if else with java, (this is in my own opinion, and everyone is entitled to said opinions)

So I sorted the Jquery and Javascripts in each section if external files.

I use toggle to hide P and "a" attributes and showed said attributes, but i find it easier to do buttons instead of links such as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="blah();"></a>
```

and made it to

```
<button onclick="blah();"></button>
```

This allows me to go directly with the onclick event and not have an href a blank path that can easily cause issues, such as viruses etc.  Some functions will be inert in javascript but active in jquery.

If there are different methods lemme know!